# How to fix error: 'Cannot find name 'describe'?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use 'countries-data' module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/countries-data) to make country picker. After npm installing I copied code from the example but after build I received error:

...is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

I solved this problem but next I received another error:

Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`  and then add `jest` or `mocha` to the types field in your tsconfig.

As I understand it's necessary for testing, but I don't know how to fix this.
I have tried to install jest, but nothing has changed

Comment: "I solved this problem but next I received another error:" - how did you solve this?

Comment: @naeramarth7, I added `"include": [
    ".",
    "../node_modules/countries-data/**/*"
]` in tsconfig